# Immutable JS - Adding/Removing in a List nested inside a Map

Tags: redux, immutable.js

Working on a redux appilcation i have the following data structure which is being converted to an immutable object using fromJS()

```
import { Map, push, fromJS } from 'immutable';

const initialState = fromJS({
filter: "cards",
contacts: [
    {
        name: "Someone 1",
        email: "someone@example.com",
        phone: "+1 900 78601",
        location: "Los Angeles"
    },
]});
```

and my reducer looks something like this:

```
function contactsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_CONTACT:
        return state.get('contacts').push(Map(
          {
              name: "Someone 1",
              email: "someone@example.com",
              phone: "+1 900 78601",
              location: "Los Angeles"
          }
        ));
    default:
        return state;
}}
```

What i can't figure out is how to target that contacts array and add more contacts to it. The reducer i wrote modifies the whole structure of the new state. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out based on the answer Alex Parij gave above, which needed slight changes. here it is:

```
state.set('contacts', state.get('contacts').push(Map(
          {
            name: "Someone 1",
            email: "someone@example.com",
            phone: "+1 900 78601",
            location: "Los Angeles"
          }
)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` on the Map to update the `contacts` field with a newly updated List after you called `push` on it.

```
state.set('contacts').push(Map(
     {
        name: "Someone 1",
        email: "someone@example.com",
        phone: "+1 900 78601",
        location: "Los Angeles"
     }
 ))
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives me an error stating:  Uncaught TypeError: state.set(...).push is not a function